# Как изменить поле формы Django при наследовании от модели?

Tags: django, django-admin, django-model

Мне нужно добавить аргумент input_formats в поле под названием date. Как это сделать при наследовании от модели?

```
class EmployeeForm(ModelForm):
class Meta:
    model = Employee
    fields = ['name', 'dep', 'salary', 'position', 'date']

    widgets = {
        "name": TextInput(attrs={
                           'class': 'form-control',
                           'placeholder': 'Enter employee name... '
                            }),
        "dep": Select(attrs={
            'class': 'form-control',
        }),
        "salary": NumberInput(attrs={
            'class': 'form-control',
            'placeholder': 'Enter salary... '
        }),
        "position": TextInput(attrs={
            'class': 'form-control',
            'placeholder': 'Enter position... '
        }),
        "date": DateInput(attrs={
            'class': 'form-control',
            'placeholder': 'Enter date... '
        })
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

можно это сделать переопределив `__init__`

```
class EmployeeForm(ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['date'].input_formats = ...

    ...
    class Meta:
        ...
```